# How to get session out put when we run cmd (running multiple exe files) remotely from Jenkins using powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

How to get session output when we run cmd (running multiple exe files) remotely from Jenkins using powershell?

On Jenkins console, I can see whether the process is running or not using invoke command. But I can’t see exact output?!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215260/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-powershell-to-a-file-during-its-execution) SO question can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.