# Redirect the output of a PowerShell script to a file using command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

How to redirect the output of a PowerShell 5.0 script to a file using cmd in Windows 10? I tried the following:

```
powershell ".\myscript.ps1 | Out-File outfile.txt"
```

and:

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1 > outfile.txt
```

to no avail. The `outfile.txt` is created but remains empty. The command prompt window is run with Administrator privileges.

In a script I use:

```
Write-Host $MyVar
Write-Host $SomeOtherVar
```

to output the values to a screen.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but isn't there the option `-Command` missing?

Comment: What is being outputted from your .ps1?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Some internal info. It works as expected when run as-is and displays the output in the powershell console as expected. I would like to redirect this output to a file using `cmd`.

Comment: @Ron Does `myscript.ps1` make use of `Write-Host`? That won't be redirected in any case

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Indeed it does.

Comment: Have you tried `powershell -file myscript.ps1 > outfile.txt`? Otherwise I'd suggest posting a sample script with which this behavior is reproducable (I'm unable to)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect the output of a PowerShell to a file during its execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215260/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-powershell-to-a-file-during-its-execution)

Comment: @iRon I need a redirection when using the `cmd`.

Comment: From the accepted answer you apparently also accept answers that involve modifying the PowerShell script. [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) might be easier to implement than replacing all `Write-Host` commands. Anyways, an answer that doesn't involve changing the PowerShell script is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a script I use:
>
> ```
> Write-Host $MyVar
> Write-Host $SomeOtherVar
> ```
>
> to output the values to a screen.

Yeah, that's your problem right there! `Write-Host` writes the information straight to the screen buffer of the host application, so the standard output stream will never actually see anything.

Change your `Write-Host` statements to `Write-Output` (or just remove them):

```
Write-Output $MyVar
Write-Output $SomeOtherVar
# or simply
$MyVar
$SomeOtherVar
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the specific [PowerShell redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6#powershell-redirection-operators):
<sub>(they appear to work at the (cmd) command prompt as wel)</sub>

Redirect the success stream (`1>`):

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1 1> outfile.txt
```

Redirect all streams (`*>`):

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1 *> outfile.txt
```