# I need help on a power shell script to create output file on C:\onsomepath after it compares a log file for a string value

Tags: powershell

```
$abc = "C:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise\BES Relay\logfile.txt"
$checkerrorlines = "GetExpectedVersionOfParent Error: Parent response did not contain a site version"

if((Get-content $abc).Contains($checkerrorlines))
{
    Write-Host "Has gather issue"
}
else
{ 
    Write-Host "No gather issue found on relay"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect the output of a PowerShell to a file during its execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215260/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-powershell-to-a-file-during-its-execution)

Comment: Please read the help about  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Then edit the question. Pick a good subject and add the actual question into the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used Get-Content to get the content- you can use [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) to set it!

```
Set-Content -Path C:\OnSomePath\Result.log -Value 'No gather issue found on relay'
```