# Is it possible to merge 2 files from different commits with given base in another commit?

Tags: git

I've encountered a problem when 2 branches were developed independently for a long time and one of the files was moved into another directory
Let's say we had a file called `src/dir1/Main.cpp` and two branches `branch1` and `branch2` with common `base`
Then they were moved the file in `branch1` and now it's called `src/dir2/Main2.cpp`
Of course both branches also modified that file independently
Now I want to rebase `branch2` on top of `branch1` and keep both changes in the file `src/dir1/Main.cpp` (original one).

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1
```

Git asks if I want to use modified or deleted version, I choose deleted one. Then I want to proceed with a merge of file `branch1:src/dir1/Main.cpp` and `<old_branch2_hash>:src/dir2/Main2.cpp` with the base of `base:src/dir1/Main.cpp`. Is it possible to do with built-in git command (that possibly calls default `mergetool`) or without using bash-like `$()` syntax? I want it to work on both linux and windows systems and without bothering with manual copying of these files and calling a merge-tool on them.

Answer (score 1):

According to [git merge-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file), try

```
git cat-file -p branch1:src/dir1/Main.cpp > current.cpp
git cat-file -p old_branch2_hash:src/dir2/Main2.cpp > other.cpp
git cat-file -p base:src/dir1/Main.cpp > base.cpp
git merge-file current.cpp base.cpp other.cpp
```

The merge result is written into `current.cpp`. There could be conflicts. After resolving the conflicts if any, you could copy `current.cpp` to overwrite the target file.

Comment: `>` syntax is not portable. It cannot be used in powershell but thanks for the link. I wonder if it can be used directly in `merge-file` command. I'll try it out shortly

Comment: @Herrgott: Surely Powershell has something equivalent...? [(Apparently Powershell 3.0 has this supported directly, without complicated workarounds.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1215260/1256452)