# how to save python console output to file

Tags: python

Assume I run python scripts everyday, and I need to receive a mail when my python script runs out with error.
In pycharm I could save the console output to file, can anyone help me how to save the console output to a file by python script.

Comment: Run it from a shell script, which can redirect output to a file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files or https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file (if on Linux) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215260/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-powershell-to-a-file-during-its-execution if on Windows. This is an *extremely common task* and well-documented for virtually all environments.

Comment: Then check if the file is empty, and mail it if not.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using Logging

It's time to become familiar with logging in python. See [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). More specifically, see [logging to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file).

From the docs:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

If you use this module for logging rather than `print`, it will send all output to a file called `example.log` (in the same folder as the program was started)

#### Redirecting stdout

If you don't want to spend the time to learn to use the logging module, the print function will do as well, but we have to slightly modify standard output for your program.

You can do the following at the start of your python script (taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/2089675)):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('example.log', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('it now prints to `example.log`')
        # the rest of your code or main function goes here
```

Comment: thanks. how can I print both in a file and console per each run of the script using the second approach?