# No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe? for simple AWScli commands when sending output to file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, aws-cli

Windows 10. cmd, mobaxterm, ps, fluent, taby , vscode terminal etc.
I have seen other similar questions and also looked at many possible solutions to this.

[image]

I should point out that other non-awscli commands outputted to a file work just fine. Only the AWScli commands show that error and do not allow me to send output to a file.

I can easily do something like c:\> dir > filename.txt and it works.

I have checked environment variables but have not found anything that I can see as a possible item to change that would solve the problem.

This is not a duplicate of the other two questions asked, but I think the root cause might be the same. No answer that would solve this problem has been found yet.

Comment: Does the `aws` command work at all? For example, what happens if you just run `c:\> aws`?

Comment: You are in PowerShell console and not cmd, so that might be the issue.

Comment: @Caldazar I have used multiple terminals and types etc as I said in the original question. Example/screenshot posted is PS but have used many other terminals.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes everything works everywhere but except when I want to send results/output to a text file when using aws commands.

Comment: Maybe this method will work for you: [How to redirect the output of a PowerShell to a file during its execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237178/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein with any other type of command, dir, ps commands etc it works. It just doesnt work for aws commands. And it used to work. Also it used to work before. Then over some time I installed vscode add ons, aws command completion and visual studio aws tookkit, aws sak, aws sam-cli etc etc..and one of those things killed the ability to pipe aws cli commands with an angle bracket to a file.  :(

Comment: The "aws command completion" sounds like it might impact how commands are typed. I'd suggest trying without that to see if it fixes things.